# VS Code + BitBucket + Bamboo

Tags: protractor, bamboo

I am new to Test Automation. In a bid to develop a framework using Protractor with Cucumber, I have used VS Code for the framework and test cases. I have linked VS Code to BitBucket as version control system. Now I am not sure how to link to Bamboo in order to run the Automation Test Suite.
I am looking to run this suite at 2 different times
1) when there is a commit to the code of the UI application
2) schedule it to run at a specific time of the day. 
Could you please point me in the right direction so I can configure this. 
P.S.: The reason I am using BitBucket and Bamboo is these are already being used in my company.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers,
Divya

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your Dev-ops engineer should help you set-up your Protractor automation suite in your dev-ops pipeline. Any typical build tool would have a capability to schedule the jobs. Key point is, you should be running **npm install** command from Bamboo which actually refers **package.json** file. Eventually your dependencies are downloaded and test script is executed after that. You can kick-off test run using script section of **package.json** file; it should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "protractor conf.js"
}
```

You can also use a VM/desktop where Selenium server standalone is running along with specific browser driver (Ex: ChromeDriver) of your choice. you can run scripts on the remote VM or You can do the same on ECS environment if you have docker images (Selenium Hub and Node) in your org.

Also, you don't link VS Code with Bitbucket. Bitbucket is the repository where you keep your automation codebase. It's version controlled too. Protractor is an API you can execute your scripts without an IDE.